# Multiple field inserting using foreach

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

i have problem when i want insert data into one field. How can i insert the data in multiple records. Here is my form.

```
 <table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </thead>

    <tr>
        <td><input name="name[]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="age[]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Roles[]" value="Dealer" class="flat-red"> Dealer
            <input type="checkbox" name="Roles[]" value="Runner" class="flat-red"> Runner</td>
    </tr>

   <tr>
        <td><input name="name[]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="age[]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Roles[]" value="Dealer" class="flat-red"> Dealer
            <input type="checkbox" name="Roles[]" value="Runner" class="flat-red"> Runner</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input name="name[]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="age[]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Roles[]" value="Dealer" class="flat-red"> Dealer
            <input type="checkbox" name="Roles[]" value="Runner" class="flat-red"> Runner</td>
    </tr>
</table>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

Can someone please help me?
Here is My PHP code:

```
$Nameasinic = $_POST['name'];
$IDNumber = $_POST['age'];
$Roles = $_POST['Roles'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($Nameasinic); $i++) 
{
    $name = $Nameasinic[$i];
    $age = $IDNumber[$i];
    $Roles1 = $Roles[$i];
    $sql_reg = "INSERT INTO owners(`Name_as_in_IC`,`ID_No`,`Roles_Dealer`)VALUES('$name','$age','$Roles')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_reg ) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

But i can't able to get checkbox values

Comment: Are you getting all data in array ?

Comment: have you tried masquerading your array in php to insert data in database ?

Comment: you can inset all checkbox data in database?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve - do you want to insert the data obtained in that form in a database? If so provide your existing code, not just the form. The SQL will also be helpful.

Comment: You tagged this with `php`, `mysql` and `foreach`, and then you show only static HTML code that in itself has nothing whatsoever to do with either of the three ... do you really think that makes any kind of sense? Please go read [ask].

Comment: i have update the PHP code

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, try it something like this....

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </thead>

    <tr>
        <td><input name="name[0]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="age[0]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Roles[0][]" value="Dealer" class="flat-red"> Dealer
            <input type="checkbox" name="Roles[0][]" value="Runner" class="flat-red"> Runner</td>
    </tr>

   <tr>
        <td><input name="name[1]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="age[1]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Roles[1][]" value="Dealer" class="flat-red"> Dealer
            <input type="checkbox" name="Roles[1][]" value="Runner" class="flat-red"> Runner</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input name="name[2]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input name="age[2]" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Roles[2][]" value="Dealer" class="flat-red"> Dealer
            <input type="checkbox" name="Roles[2][]" value="Runner" class="flat-red"> Runner</td>
    </tr>
</table>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

And in php code

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $k=>$name) 
{
    $age       = $_POST['age'][$k];
    $Roles     = implode(",",$_POST['Roles'][$k]);
    $sql_reg   = "INSERT INTO owners(`Name_as_in_IC`,`ID_No`,`Roles_Dealer`)VALUES('$name','$age','$Roles')";
    $result    = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_reg ) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
```